# PDF and CDF of the division of two Random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-function

I have two RVs; their PDF are as the followings:

\begin{split} f_{X}(x) = \frac 1 {a} e^{-\frac x {a}}\end{split}
and
\begin{split} f_{Y}(y) = \frac {y^{L-1}} {b^{L} \Gamma (L)} e^{-\frac y {b}}\end{split}

where;
a,b [Element]  Reals && a,b > 0;
L [Element]  Integers && L >= 1;

Under the above conditions I want to calculated \begin{split} f_{Z}(z) \end{split}
where \begin{split}    Z = X/Y      \end{split}

The PDF can be calculated as the follwing:
$$f_Z(z) = \int_0^{\infty}    y f_X(yz) f_Y(y)   dy$$

And the CDF can be calculated as the follwing:
$$F_Z(z) = \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{yz}       f_X(x) f_Y(y)    dx  dy$$
or
$$F_Z(z) = \int_0^{\infty}       F_X(yz) f_Y(y)     dy$$

$$F_X(yz) =   1- e^{-\frac {yz} {a}}  $$

Now to get the PDF of Z; the result for the above integration is: $$ f_Z(z) =  \frac {a^L*b*L} {(a+b*z)^{L+1}} $$

And the CDF of Z is:

$$  F_Z(z) =  1-\left(\frac{a}{a+b z}\right)^L  $$

How to check if these results are correct?

Comment: $Y$ is not exponential, it has a Gamma distribution.

Comment: I usually do a numerical experiment with R (http://www.r-project.org/) to validate derivations such as this. Sampling your two distributions (say, a thousand times), computing $X/Y$, and plotting the resulting distribution vs. the distribution you derived should only take a few lines of code in R.

Comment: What is the question actually?

Comment: Where did parameter $c$ come from?

Comment: @Did How to check if these results are correct?

Comment: @wolfies sorry it must be `b` I will correct it.

Comment: "How to check if these results are correct?" By following the computations in your post line after line and checking that these are correct. They are.

Answer (score 1):

Simulate them.  Write a quick computer program (Mathematica or Matlab (with Statistics toolbox) or octave) to simulate all three random variables, sample each 1000 times, and see if the associated empirical distributions are similar.

Comment: I hadn't seen @fgp's comment when I wrote this, which is essentially identical.  Funny we both chose 1K samples.

Answer (score 1):

It can be verified in Maple as follows: $$with(Statistics):
X := RandomVariable(Exponential(a)):
Y := RandomVariable(Gamma(b, L)):
Z := X/Y;
CDF(Z, t);
  $$ produces $$\cases{0&$t\leq 0$\cr - \left( bt+a \right) ^{-L}{a}^{L}+1&$0<t$\cr}.  $$